# I am desperate to find the name of this brick

Tags: part-identification

Please help me find the name of this brick!

I am trying to build a Lego locomotive MOC and these headlights parts, the yellow ones would fit perfectly with my design, but I can't find the name of this one no matter how much I searched.

[image]

[image]

I would greatly appreciate if someone can recognize it and help me identify it!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks pretty much like this part (tilted by 90°):

[image]

[Brick Modified 2 x 2 with Pin Hole, Rotation Joint Socket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48169#T=C)

I recognized it by the small sloped parts next to the cylinder.
But apparently, this part was never produced in yellow. When looking closely at the pictures, the yellow has a different tone than the other yellow parts next to it. I think it might have been repainted.

Comment: OMG you are soo good! Thank you so much!

Comment: @BlueBrick Thanks, i recognized it because i like to use this part as engines on spaceships.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

Those headlights are made by mounting a Brick Round 2x2 in yellow with the studs towards the train body, and then adding a trans-clear boat stud as the light’s lens. The whole construction seems to be fixed in place with a bar, judging from the little light-bluish-gray tip sticking out into the lens.

Comment: The round brick would be to big, please look at the latest model here is a picture attached, he updated it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wssjR.jpg